# How do I pack a flask app into a pex file?

Tags: python, flask, deployment, binaryfiles

So I have a python app made up of multiple modules which i can run with the following:

```
set FLASK_APP=myApp:get_app 
flask run
```

which works fine on any machine I run it on. However, I want to now pack this into a single file which I can run. I've found [pex](https://pex.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) which looks like it can solve my problem, but I can't get it working.

So far I've tried creating a .pex file with the requirements and the entry point but nothing happens when I run it. the pex construction line is:

```
pex --python-shebang='path/to/my/python' -r requirements.txt -e myApp:main -o myApp.pex
```

Where the main function runs:

```py
def main():
    app = get_app()
    app.run()
```

however now when I run `myApp.pex` nothing happens, what am I doing wrong?